# What caused win blue screen when using Python3.4 urllib.request to to download large number of images

Tags: python, image, download, urllib, large-data

I was trying to download a large number of images from web based on 3 columns from a table in a pre-built database. The three columns I retrieved are imageId, imageName, and imageUrl. Same imageId always corresponds to same imageName, but the same imageId-iamgeName pair may corresponds to multiple image urls (see e.g. below). My goal was to just download all these images and save the multiple images with same imageId-imageName pair folders. For example, the table below would create three folders named "1_flower" (including 2 images) "2_bowl" (including 1 image) and 10_sky(including one image). The actual database has about **58,000 rows** (i.e. images)

The problem is that running the code in the middle caused windows suddenly become **blue screen with the message "IRQL Not Less Or Equal"**. I've tried to run the program multiple times and it always caused the blue screen (at slightly different time periods each run) in the middle of running (only downloaded after about 100 images).

I've done a lot of search and no luck. It seems too me **some memory issue caused by urllib.request.urlretrieve**, but not sure where exactly was wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
imageId, imageName, imageUrl
============================

 - 1,        flower,      /xxx/flowerPicOne.jpg
 - 2,        bowl,     /xxx/bowPic.jpg
 - 1,        flower,      /xxx/flowerPicTwo.png
 - 10,       sky,         /xxx/skyPic.jpg
 - ...
 - ...
```

---

```
import sqlite3
import os
import urllib.request

conn = sqlite3.connect("myDatabase.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('SELECT imageId, imageName, imageUrl FROM imageTable')
rows = c.fetchall()
existingFolderNameList = []

for row in rows:
    folderName = str(row[0]) + '_' + row[1].replace(" ", "").replace("/","-").replace("'","")
    imUrl = "http://www.someCommonHeader.com/" + row[2].replace(" ", "")
    if folderName not in existingFolderNameList:
        os.makedirs(folderName)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(imUrl, folderName + "/" + row[2].replace(" ", "").replace("/","-"))
        existingFolderNameList.append(folderName)
    else:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(imUrl, folderName + "/" + row[2].replace(" ", "").replace("/","-"))

# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()

# Close connection
conn.close()
```

[image: Dump file by bluescreenview]
[image: Blue screen pic]

Comment: Odds are this isn't your program.  You will need the full detail from the crash -- there's a good chance it's a badly-behaving device driver.

Comment: @Joe Thanks! Did you mean some hard device or driver-related problem on my computer is the cause? I will repeat the problem and add a photo of the bluescreen

Comment: @plg519 Interesting suggestion by Joe. Could you try implementing the same program on a different dev environment to rule out the program being the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I see based on the image you use Windows 7, so what you probably need to do is get a newer copy of ntoskrnl.exe for Windows 7 and put it where the original was.

What the problem may be is either failing memory, causing IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL, or either a problem with your code or the program.

So either the program has a few bugs causing the bluescreen, or ntoskrnl needs to be installed. But you may need to be specific for which ntosknrl, because maybe for example you installed Windows 2000 or Windows XP ntoskrnl by accident, which may screw up the PC. So try searching "Windows 7 NTOSKRNL download" and then replace yours with that copy. It may not matter which NTOSKRNL for Windows 7 version you have. It could be an Ultimate ntosknrl being replaced with Home Premium. It's not that I've ever tried it because I don't own Windows 7. But it did happen once with a Windows XP during a YouTube video that I received IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL. But that was years ago, when I didn't know much about computers.

The program may need a re-install if the ntoskrnl idea fails.

...you know what, I don't even think there's a difference between the ntoskrnl in Windows versions. I believe there is, so just to be safe, search Windows 7 ntoskrnl.

Comment: ...or whatever the file name is, I may be wrong by ntoskrnl.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my 4-year old question! Mario. I've switched to mac and this problem is not urgent anymore, but still appreciate your answer and hope it can benefit others :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to hear from you, and able to help you out. There's still people out there having problems with Macs, too! One YouTube guy can burn blank DVDs, but not ones with files in them. Others experience Sad Macs, an error similar to the Windows Bluescreen, but black and with a dead computer icon with 16 numbers (or more/less) resembling a stopcode (error code). Mac doesn't use stopcodes like IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL how Windows does. My mom also got her Mac nearly infected by a fake antivirus going around. Better be careful which sites you visit; Windows OR Macintosh! -MarioGamerExpt